# How to break the wp_link_pages in two lines

Tags: paginate-links

I have 4 videos in my single post which are being displayed using nextpage quicktag.
To style pagination i am using the follwing code in single.php

```
    <div class="pagelink"><?php wp_link_pages('before=LQ &pagelink=Chapter %'); ?></div>
```

its giving me output like *LQ Chapter 1 Chapter 2 Chapter 3 Chapter4*

But i want to display like

*LQ Chapter 1 Chapter 2*

*HQ Chapter 1 Chapter 2*

in seprate lines . What i can do for this?

Desired html output should be like this

```
<p class="link-pages">
    LQ
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 1</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 2</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 3</span>
</p>
<p class="link-pages">
    HQ
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 1</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 2</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 3</span>
</p>
```

and for this i will add 6 chapter content in my post using the 
like

```
Chapter 1<!--nextpage-->
Chapter 2<!--nextpage-->
Chapter 3 <!--nextpage-->
Chapter 4 <!--nextpage--> // this will become chapter 1 in HQ
Chatper 5 <!--nextpage-->// this will become chapter 2 in HQ
Chapter 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially use the `before`, `after`, and `separator` arguments passed to [`wp_link_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) to wrap each item in a span, then target the spans via CSS.

Here's your current code:

```
wp_link_pages(
    'before=LQ &pagelink=Chapter %'
);
```

Converting to an array, because it's easier to follow/manipulate:

```
wp_link_pages( array( 
    'before' => 'LQ ',
    'pagelink' => 'Chapter %'
) );
```

Let's modify it:

```
wp_link_pages( array( 
    'before' => '<p class="link-pages">LQ<span class="page-link">',
    'after' => '</span></p>',
    'separator' => '</span><span>',
    'pagelink' => 'Chapter %'
) );
```

This will produce output like (line breaks added for readability):

```
<p class="link-pages">
    LQ
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 1</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 2</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 3</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 4</span>
</p>
```

Then you can use CSS to style the `<span>`s according to your needs.

### Edit

Alternative/related suggestion:

You can pass `'echo' => false` to *return* the markup as a string:

```
$page_links = wp_link_pages( array( 
    'before' => '<p class="link-pages">LQ<span class="page-link">',
    'after' => '</span></p>',
    'separator' => '</span><span>',
    'pagelink' => 'Chapter %',
    // Return, don't echo
    'echo' => false
) );
```

Then, you can use whatever tools at your disposal (PHP, RegEx, etc.) to manipulate `$page_links` however necessary to suit your needs.

### Note

Please note: CSS and PHP/RegEx are *off-topic* for WPSE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer But i am little confuse. I have to display two lines in pagination. Output should be like this
<p class="link-pages">
    LQ
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 1</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 2</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 3</span>
</p>
<p class="link-pages">
    HQ
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 1</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 2</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 3</span>
</p>

and for this i will add 6 chapter content in my post using the <!--nextpage-->

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add additional details/code. Comments aren't well-suited for formatted code, and could make important details difficult to find.

Comment: plz check i have edited the question

Comment: off the topic : where should i write the php/regex code in single.php itself ?

Comment: That would be one way. Or you could wrap it in a custom function (declared in `functions.php`), and then call your custom function in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use these to separate the links?

```
next_post_link()
previous_post_link()
```

Comment: Those functions link to previous and next *adjacent posts*. The OP is linking to separate pages of a single, *paginated* post.